# EPPlus wrap and set cell height simultaneously

Tags: c#, epplus

I need to wrap text and set maximum height for a cell in excel generated using EPPlus v4.0 library

Code:

```
    _worksheet.Cells[rowIndex, columnFrom, rowIndex, columnTo].Style.WrapText = true;
    _worksheet.Row(rowIndex).CustomHeight = true;
    _worksheet.Row(rowIndex).Height = 5;
```

I also tried without setting CustomHeight = true.

Didn't set auto sizing: ie, didn't use below code

```
    _workSheet.Cells["A1:G1"].AutoFitColumns();
```

Comment: But what is the current behavior? What went wrong with that code?

Comment: currently the generated excel doesn't have the given height, it alters according to the text content inside the cell.

Answer (score 0):

I would just loop through the cells you want to set and then use as you have something like the following:

```
for( int j=1, j <= maxColumns, j++)
{
    for( int i=1, i<= maxRows, i++)
    {
       _worksheet.Row(i).Height = 5;
       _worksheet.Cells[i, j].Style.WrapText = true;
    }
}
```

And set accordingly depending on which columns/rows you want to set.

Comment: Let me try this.